# config() não retorna o que foi configurado

Tags: php, laravel, variáveis-de-ambiente

Tenho uma classe `Foobar.php` que nela têm um `return []` com alguns itens que estão apontados do `.env`, neste formato:

**Foobar.php**:

```php
function decode_ifnot_null() {} ... // método que auxilia na obtenção de valores de arquivos

return [
    "CONFIG_A" => env("CONFIG_A", true),
    "CONFIG_B" => decode_ifnot_null(env("CONFIG_B")),
    "CONFIG_C" => env("CONFIG_C", true),
];
```

No meu **.env**, está assim:

```php
CONFIG_A=the quick fox
CONFIG_B=C:\\users\\admin\\arquivo.json
CONFIG_C=jumps over the lazy dog
```

Porém quando eu chamo o método `config("CONFIG_A")`, eu recebo um `null`. Quando eu chamo o `env("CONFIG_A")`, eu recebo `the quick fox`.

O arquivo *foobar.php* está dentro de `/config/`.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estou enferrujado de Laravel, mas até aonde me lembro o "parâmetro" da função `config()` deveria se referir ao nome do arquivo separado por ponto para pegar um valor especifico, por exemplo, seu arquivo se chama Foobar.php, então isto deveira ser usado assim:

```
$variavel = config('Foobar.CONFIG_A');
```

Para pegar o outro:

```
$variavel = config('Foobar.CONFIG_B');
```

Se seu arquivo se chamasse cyberpotato.php, deveria ser:

```
config('cyberpotato.CONFIG_B');
```

Se desejar pegar o array todo, deve ser:

```
var_dump(config('cyberpotato'));
```

Comment: Vocês adoram errar meu nome. Obrigado de qualquer forma!

Comment: @CypherPotato o CyberPotato é o seu BOT de estimação :)

Comment: Considerável haha